# System.IO.File.Create file cannot download ? in mvc 5 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, file-access, system.io.file

The file that is created by `System.IO.File.Create` cannot download like the file created by `HttpPostedFileBase.SaveAs`.

My code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SaveasMP4(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Data/"), file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                if (!extension.Equals(".mp4"))
                {
                    var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
                    string tempFileName = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf('.')) + ".mp4";
                    using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Data/"), tempFileName)))
                    {
                        ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(path, fileStream, Format.mp4);
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
            return View();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

if the file is mp4 can be download by using file.SaveAs(path). But if the file is in other format it convert to mp4 successfully by using NReco.VideoConverter and cannot download because it create by System.IO.File.Create(tempFileName) . Just i can download by using ftp.
Is the problem in file access permission?
If it is what should I do in file access permission?

Comment: What are `tempFileName` and `filess`?

Comment: Well what happens at the moment? Is there an exception? Why are you not using `fileStream`?

Comment: I already used FileStream but cannot work.
and  when i try to download  it show there is no file.
Actually the file in the serve  and i can download by ftp.

Comment: You haven't shown us the mvc action that streams that file result to the user.  Can you post that code please?

Comment: Thanks  Slicksim. I post the code.

Comment: You must add write permissions for folder "~/Data/" for iis worker process user

Comment: I add the permissions for folder "~/Data/" that way i can download the file if created by file.SaveAs(path).

Comment: What is the actual exception thrown? No point in adding permissions for an invalid path error.  The exception message would help but the full exception text is even better as it includes the call stack and any inner exceptions (ie call e.ToString())

Comment: also you can use Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension instead of substring

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos. when i work locally it work very well. But when i work in remote host the file cannot download.And it show network error or file not found.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is related to file permissions policy that belong to the server.
If the file is made by internal process like FFMpeg DLL (C++ library) the server block the IIS user from download the file.
So I contact with the server team and they give permissions to IIS user to download the file that made by FFMpeg DLL.